# How do I represent morning and midnight timings in ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime, time

I need to store and retrieve restaurant timings in simple methods like `morning` and `midnight`. What I am doing now is:

```
def morning
    Time.new("6:30 am")
end

def midnight
    Time.new("12:00 am")
end
```

I can compare timings now but this seems to be the wrong way to do it and then I don't know how to read those time values back for a method like:

```
    def open?(time)
        time >= morning && time <= midnight 
    end
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: If you are using ruby 1.9+, you can use a range for the times.  That makes most sense to me.

Comment: Could you refer to me to the right api documentation please? I am using ruby 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Using the `chronic` gem I was able to do this:

```
    def opens_at
        morning
    end

    def closes_at
        midnight
    end

    def open?(time)
        Chronic.parse(time) >= morning && Chronic.parse(time) < midnight
    end

    private
    def morning
        Chronic.parse("6:30 am")
    end

    def midnight
        Chronic.parse("midnight")
    end
```

This works for comparisons

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who do not like having a extra gem in gemfile for smaller things, will go for:

```
def morning
    DateTime.now.beginning_of_day + (6.5).hours
end

def midnight
   DateTime.now.end_of_day
   # Or DateTime.now.at_midnight + 1 
end
```

there are a lot more options DateTime gives us like:
 :at_beginning_of_day, :at_beginning_of_month, :at_beginning_of_quarter, :at_beginning_of_week, :at_beginning_of_year, :at_end_of_month, :at_end_of_quarter, :at_end_of_week, :at_end_of_year, :at_midnight, :awesome_inspect, :awesome_print, :beginning_of_day, :beginning_of_month, :beginning_of_quarter, :beginning_of_week, :beginning_of_year, :wday, :sunday?, :monday?, :tuesday?, :wednesday?, :thursday?, :friday?, :saturday?

Just do( trust me you wont regret it):
`DateTime.now.methods.sort`